# Name of that "farewell" salute

Tags: word-request

I tried (and failed) to find the name of this salute:

[image: Arthur salute]

(Sorry for the low quality, the character is quite far from the camera)

From what I can tell, it's used to informally signify a "farewell" in a sort of sarcastic way, and it seems to be quite common as a form of saying "bye" to someone over a long physical distance (like across a street, or, in the case of the video, from a rooftop). It also seems to be pretty common with snipers/marksmen. The defining feature is that it's done with 2 fingers, and that the person doing it sort of "darts" their hand out towards whoever they're talking to.

Comment: Why do you think there is a specific name for it? And where is the footage from, is it a game?

Comment: For an American, that looks like a standard military salute.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a gesture particularly used by native speakers of English. I see no reason to believe it has a name in English. Perhaps just a slightly exaggerated gesture to be seen at a distance.  It isn't something formally required by the military.

Comment: Are you wanting the official name of the salute, or a term for the salute used ironically? Questions about military terminology are probably better asked at History SE, where there are a lot of military history experts. If it's sarcastic, then "ironic salute" would be fine.

Comment: I'm asking because it's a really common salute, both in media and in some conversations. Calling it whatever sounds right is one thing, but the actual terminology is much more important to me, because I want to find out the gesture's origin, historical usage, changes in meaning, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the form of salute you mention is a single, specifically-named, type of salute, but rather a combination of at least two idiomatic forms of salute which might be used separately or together in particular contexts.

As Josef Baskin mentioned, the American military, presidents, movie portrayals of the military, etc, often give salutes with what appears to be an additional emphatic flourish that I presume has developed over time. It involves the jerking of the hand away from the head after giving the 'traditional' salute of placing the side of the right hand against or near the forehead. This is done with all four fingers and the thumb.

In the context of, for instance, a farewell, or when the salute marks an especially significant moment - say if a soldier is saying farewell with the expectation of dying imminently, or wants to make some other point, which could even be rhetorical in nature (say, implying sarcastic 'loyalty') - or if the salute simply needs to be seen at a greater distance (as in your image), the emphasis provided by the jerked hand simply becomes greater according to the context, transforming from a more minor movement of the hand by a few inches away from the head into an almost 'Roman' salute.

As far as I can see from a quick [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salute#United_States), the 'jerked' American salute is not officially recognised in any way. It is simply something that has become common, at least in popular media, above all movies. I have no idea if it's actually used frequently by the military, although I'm pretty certain presidents often do it when returning the salutes of uniformed service people.

The two-fingered aspect of the salute I believe is separate. I can't find any specific source, but in my own experience in North America, people in the USA and Canada use this form of salute in either civilian or informal military contexts as a way to 'soften' the implication of an actual military salute. It can be used as a kind of 'OK boss' or 'as you wish' signal, and the hand jerk again just adds emphasis, or makes the salute more visible far away. My personal impression is that the two finger salute is usually deliberately 'childish' ... a bit like an old-fashioned Wolf-Cub two-fingered salute or a Boy Scout three-fingered salute. It's fair to say that in most cases it is likely to be made with anything between a hostile, sarcastic, ironic or gently humorous intent. It is therefore not specifically a 'farewell' salute, but a tongue-in-cheek/humorous indication of deference to another.

This was the way the enormously popular late twentieth-century British comedian Benny Hill used salutes in his TV shows. Although I can't find an example of him doing a two fingered salute in the style done today in the US and Canada (with fingers together), he certainly did both full (British army style) and 'Wolf Cub' salutes as a way of making his characters appear ludicrous. The salute you identify is at least somewhat in this tradition.

The image of Captain America, below, may hint further at the reason for the two-fingered variety of salute. In theory, in most western English-speaking nations, and certainly the USA, salutes are not meant to be made by people who are not members of the military, or who are not in uniform, or even if in uniform but not wearing a hat. In that tradition, a full military salute, especially if made by a former service-person, would be considered 'wrong' and even a serious faux-pas, if given while wearing civilian clothes. A two-fingered salute would therefore be an appropriate substitute. In time this two-fingered 'informal' or 'rhetorical' salute could even make it back into informal military contexts.

**Benny Hill doing a 'Wolf Cub' two-fingered salute:**

[image: Benny Hill - Wolf Cub salute]

**Benny Hill doing a full British army salute:**

[image: Benny Hill - British army salute]

**Barney Stinson, 'How I Met Your Mother':**

[image: Barney Stinson, 'How I Met Your Mother', two fingered salute]

**Captain America - Non-sarcastic, non-military salute:**

[image: Captain America - Non-sarcastic, non-military salute]

Comment: THANK YOU. Honestly, the only actually useful answer. Well-written, well-researched, and actually answers my question.